# Почему неправильно выполняется 8 и 15 тест?

Tags: java, методы, linked-list

Не могу решить проблему, тест 8 и 15 выполняются не правильно. Можете дать подсказку что не так.

```
public interface Container extends Iterable<Object> {

// Removes all of the elements.
void clear();

// Returns the number of elements.
int size();

// Returns a string representation of this container.
String toString();

// Returns an iterator over elements.
// Iterator must implements the remove method.
Iterator<Object> iterator();}
```

```
public interface List extends Container {

// Inserts the specified element at the beginning.
void addFirst(Object element);

// Appends the specified element to the end.
void addLast(Object element);

// Removes the first element.
void removeFirst();

// Removes the last element.
void removeLast();

// Returns the first element.
Object getFirst();

// Returns the last element.
Object getLast();

// Returns the first occurrence of the specified element.
// Returns null if no such element.
// (use 'equals' method to check an occurrence)
Object search(Object element);

// Removes the first occurrence of the specified element.
// Returns true if this list contained the specified element.
// (use 'equals' method to check an occurrence)
boolean remove(Object element);}
```

```
public class ListImpl implements List {

int size = 0;
private Node first;
private Node last;

private static class Node {
    public Object data;
    public Node next;
    public Node previous;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return data.toString();
    }

    public Node(Object data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}

@Override
public void addFirst(Object element) {
    Node currentNode = new Node(element);
    if (first == null) {
        first = currentNode;
        last = currentNode;
    } else {
        currentNode.next = first;
        first.previous = currentNode;
        first = currentNode;
    }
    size++;
}

@Override
public void addLast(Object element) {
    Node currentNode = new Node(element);
    if (last == null) {
        first = currentNode;
        last = currentNode;
    } else {
        currentNode.previous = last;
        last.next = currentNode;
        last = currentNode;
    }
    size++;
}

@Override
public void removeFirst() {
    if (first == null) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    } else {
        Node nextNode = first.next;
        nextNode.previous = null;
        first = first.next;
        size--;
    }
}

@Override
public void removeLast() {
    if (last == null) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    } else {
        Node previousNode = last.previous;
        previousNode.next = null;
        last = last.previous;
        size--;
    }
}

@Override
public Object getFirst() {
    if (first == null) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    } else
        return first.data;
}

@Override
public Object getLast() {
    if (last == null) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    } else
        return last.data;
}

@Override
public Object search(Object element) {
    Node currentNode = first;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (currentNode.data.equals(element)) {
            return currentNode.data;
        }
        currentNode = currentNode.next;
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public boolean remove(Object element) {
    Node currentNode = first;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (currentNode.data.equals(element)) {
            Node next = currentNode.next;
            Node previous = currentNode.previous;
            if (next != null) {
                next.previous = previous;

            }
            if (previous != null) {
                previous.next = next;

            }
            size--;
            return true;
        }
      //  currentNode = currentNode.next;
    }
    size--;
    return false;
}

@Override
public void clear() {
    size = 0;
    first = null;
    last = null;
}

@Override
public int size() {
    return size;
}

@Override
public Iterator<Object> iterator() {
    return new IteratorImpl();
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    if (size == 0) {
        return "[]";
    } else {
        IteratorImpl iterator = new IteratorImpl();
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder("[");
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Node currentNode = (Node) iterator.next();
            result.append(currentNode.data.toString());
            if (iterator.hasNext()) {
                result.append(", ");
            } else {
                result.append("]");
            }
        }
        return result.toString();
    }
}

public class IteratorImpl implements Iterator {

    private Node lastReturned;
    private Node nextNode;
    private int index = 0;


    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return index < size;
    }

    @Override
    public Object next() {
        if (!hasNext()) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
        index++;
        if (lastReturned == null) {
            lastReturned = first;
            return lastReturned;
        }
        lastReturned = lastReturned.next;
        return lastReturned;
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
        if (index == 0) {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
        ListImpl.this.remove(lastReturned.data);
        index--;
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    test1();
    test2();
    test3();
    test4();
    test5();
    test6();
    test7();
    test8();
    test9();
    test10();
    test11();
    test12();
    test13();
    test14();
    test15();
}

private static void test1() {
    System.out.println("\n" + "--------------------------------------");
    List list = new ListImpl();
    Class c = list.getClass();

    // must be 1
    System.out.println(c.getInterfaces().length);

    // must be List
    System.out.println(c.getInterfaces()[0].getSimpleName());

    // must be java.lang.Object
    System.out.println(c.getSuperclass().getName());

    // must be 1
    System.out.println(c.getInterfaces()[0].getInterfaces().length);

    // must be Container
    System.out.println(c.getInterfaces()[0].getInterfaces()[0].getSimpleName());

    // must be 1
    System.out.println(c.getInterfaces()[0].getInterfaces()[0].getInterfaces().length);

    // must be java.lang.Iterable
    System.out.println(c.getInterfaces()[0].getInterfaces()[0].getInterfaces()[0].getName());

    /* an output must be as the following:
    *************************************
    1
    List
    java.lang.Object
    1
    Container
    1
    java.lang.Iterable
    *************************************
    */
}

private static void test2() {
    System.out.println("\n" + "--------------------------------------");

    List list = new ListImpl();
    list.addLast("A");
    list.addLast("B");
    list.addLast("C");

    System.out.println(list);
    System.out.println(list.size());

    list.clear();
    System.out.println(list);
    System.out.println(list.size());

    list.addLast("A");
    list.addLast("B");
    list.addLast("C");

    System.out.println(list);
    System.out.println(list.size());

    /* an output must be as the following:
    *************************************
    [A, B, C]
    3
    []
    0
    [A, B, C]
    3
    *************************************
    */
}

private static void test3() {
    System.out.println("\n" + "--------------------------------------");

    List list = new ListImpl();
    list.addFirst("A");
    list.addLast("B");
    list.addFirst("C");

    System.out.println(list);
    System.out.print(list.getFirst());
    System.out.print(list.getLast());

    /* an output must be as the following:
    *************************************
    [C, A, B]
    CB
    *************************************
    */
}

private static void test4() {
    System.out.println("\n" + "--------------------------------------");
    List list = new ListImpl();
    list.addFirst("c");
    list.addFirst("b");
    list.addFirst("a");
    list.addLast("A");
    list.addLast("B");
    list.addLast("C");

    System.out.println(list);

    /* an output must be as the following:
    *************************************
    [a, b, c, A, B, C]
    *************************************
    */
}

private static void test5() {
    System.out.println("\n" + "--------------------------------------");
    List list = new ListImpl();
    list.addLast("A");
    list.addLast("B");
    list.addLast("C");

    for (Object element : list) {
        System.out.print(element);
    }

    /* an output must be as the following:
    *************************************
    ABC
    *************************************
    */
}

private static void test6() {
    System.out.println("\n" + "--------------------------------------");
    List list = new ListImpl();
    list.addLast("A");
    list.addLast("B");
    list.addLast("C");

    Iterator it = list.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        System.out.print(it.next());
    }
    System.out.println();
    it = list.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        System.out.print(it.next());
    }

    /* an output must be as the following:
    *************************************
    ABC
    ABC
    *************************************
    */
}

private static void test7() {
    System.out.println("\n" + "--------------------------------------");
    List list = new ListImpl();
    list.addLast("A");
    list.addLast("B");
    list.addLast("C");

    Iterator it = list.iterator();
    System.out.println(it.next());
    it.remove();
    System.out.println(it.next());
    it.remove();
    System.out.println(it.next());
    it.remove();
    System.out.println(list);

    /* an output must be as the following:
    *************************************
    A
    B
    C
    []
    *
    *************************************
    */
}

private static void test8() {
    System.out.println("\n" + "--------------------------------------");
    List list = new ListImpl();
    list.addLast("A");
    list.addFirst("B");
    list.addLast("C");


    Iterator it = list.iterator();

    System.out.println(it.next());
    System.out.println(it.next());
    System.out.println(it.next());
    it.remove();
    System.out.println(list);

    it = list.iterator();

    System.out.println(it.next());
    it.remove();
    System.out.println(list);

    it = list.iterator();

    System.out.println(it.next());
    it.remove();
    System.out.println(list);

    /* an output must be as the following:
    *************************************
    B
    A
    C
    [B, A]
    B
    [A]
    A
    []
    *************************************
    */
}

private static void test9() {
    System.out.println("\n" + "--------------------------------------");
    List list = new ListImpl();
    list.addLast("A");
    list.addLast("B");
    list.addLast("C");

    Iterator it = list.iterator();
    System.out.println(it.next());
    it.remove();
    try {
        it.remove();
    } catch (IllegalStateException ex) {
        System.out.println("exception");
    }

    /* an output must be as the following:
    *************************************
    A
    exception
    *************************************
    */
}

private static void test10() {
    System.out.println("\n" + "--------------------------------------");
    List list = new ListImpl();
    list.addLast("A");
    list.addLast("B");
    list.addLast("C");

    Iterator it = list.iterator();
    try {
        it.remove();
    } catch (IllegalStateException ex) {
        System.out.println("exception");
    }

    /* an output must be as the following:
    *************************************
    exception
    *************************************
    */
}

private static void test11() {
    System.out.println("\n" + "--------------------------------------");
    List list = new ListImpl();
    list.addFirst("B");
    list.addLast("C");
    list.addFirst("A");

    System.out.println(list);

    list.removeFirst();
    System.out.println(list);

    list.removeFirst();
    System.out.println(list);

    /* an output must be as the following:
    *************************************
    [A, B, C]
    [B, C]
    [C]
    *************************************
    */
}

private static void test12() {
    System.out.println("\n" + "--------------------------------------");
    List list = new ListImpl();
    list.addFirst("B");
    list.addLast("C");
    list.addFirst("A");

    System.out.println(list);

    list.removeLast();
    System.out.println(list);

    list.removeLast();
    System.out.println(list);

    /* an output must be as the following:
    *************************************
    [A, B, C]
    [A, B]
    [A]
    *************************************
    */
}

private static void test13() {
    System.out.println("\n" + "--------------------------------------");
    List list = new ListImpl();
    list.addFirst("B");
    list.addLast("C");
    list.addFirst("A");

    System.out.println(list);
    System.out.println(list.getFirst());
    System.out.println(list.getLast());

    /* an output must be as the following:
    *************************************
    [A, B, C]
    A
    C
    *************************************
    */
}

private static void test14() {
    System.out.println("\n" + "--------------------------------------");
    List list = new ListImpl();
    list.addFirst(3);
    list.addFirst(2);
    list.addFirst(1);

    System.out.println(list);
    System.out.println(list.search(1));
    System.out.println(list.search(2));
    System.out.println(list.getLast());

    /* an output must be as the following:
    *************************************
    [1, 2, 3]
    1
    2
    3
    *************************************
    */
}

private static void test15() {
    System.out.println("\n" + "--------------------------------------");
    List list = new ListImpl();
    list.addLast(1);
    list.addLast(2);
    list.addLast(1);

    list.remove(1);
    System.out.println(list);

    list.remove(2);
    System.out.println(list);

    Iterator it = list.iterator();
    System.out.println(it.next());

    /* an output must be as the following:
    *************************************
    [2, 1]
    [1]
    1
    *************************************
    */

}}
```

Comment: это не тесты, а Филькина грамота, используйте JUnit для написания тестов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private Node searchNodeByData(Object data) {
  Node current = first;
  while (current != null) {
    if (current.data.equals(data)) {
      return current;
    }
    current = curent.next;
  }
  return null;
}

@Override
public boolean remove(Object element) {
  Node current = searchNodeByData(element);
  if (current == null) {
    return false;
  }

  Node next = current.next;
  Node previous = current.previous;
  if (next != null) {
    next.previous = previous;
  }
  if (previous != null) {
    previous.next = next;
  }

  if (current == first)
    first = next;
  if (current == last)
    last = previous;

  size--;
  return true;
}
```

---

```
@Override
public void remove() {
  if (index == 0) {
    throw new IllegalStateException();
  }
  Node prev = lastReturned.previous;
  ListImpl.this.remove(lastReturned.data);
  lastReturned = prev;
  index--;
}
```